# How to change Spyder Python version

Tags: python, python-3.x, version, spyder

I am using Python 3.7, because some of my modules need it. But Tensorflow requires Python 3.5/3.6, so I installed Python 3.5, now how do I easily change the version of Python my Spyder is using, without crating new Virtual Environments and stuff like that? (note: I am not using Anaconda)

(If it helps, I am using Windows 10)

Answer (score -1):

In your script write this at the top

```
#! “C:\<location of python>\python.exe”
```

Where the location is the location of your desired python install. I have version 37 and 36 installed. So for 36 I went to c:\program files\python36\python.exe

To check that your script is running the right version you can type:

```
import platform
print(platform.python_version())
```